# Coverity warning::"cc" clobber ignored for htons() and ntohs()

Tags: c, sockets, coverity

Why does Coverity generate warning

```
> "cc" clobber ignored
```

for the function calls htons() and ntohs() in the code mentioned below?

```
lSocketAddr.sin_port = htons(kUDPServerPort);
```

I have googled and found out that this warning also appears with Intel Compiler chain. What does "cc" clobber ignored mean? Does it mean that htons() and ntohs()should not be used for secure programming? Is there any solution to solve the warning? Are there any alternative apis htons() and ntohs()?

System Configuration:

1. Coverity 5.3
2. RedHat 6
3. GCC version 4.4.5

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means that the function is marked as a function that clobbers the [conditions flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29) in the processor, but this marking is being ignored.

[This commit](http://git.openvz.org/?p=linux-2.6.32-openvz;a=commitdiff;h=d6bb7a1ad326f56f0793353c59348554f84b513c) to OpenViz shows the "cc" clobber being added, it's an argument to the inline `asm` statement, it looks like this:

```
asm("bsch %2,%0" : "=r"(bit) : "0"(0), "r"(x & -x) : "cc");
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                                    hello!
```

Not so sure about why the warning is generated though, perhaps Coverity trying to communicate that the functions in question contain such `asm`, but it can't take the "cc" information into account in its analysis?

I don't think there's reason to abandon the function(s) based on this warning, the warning seems fairly "meta", not about the code itself but about Coverity's processing of the code.

Note: I've never used Coverity.